Powershell remove image from word document
I'm writing a script to look over every word document in a directory and remove any images. This is because I have a client that needs to debrand a large set of documents.
I have written a powershell script and it works for most. However I have come across a document and the image does not register in powershell as a shape, inline shape, shape in a table, shape in a textbox. I can't seem to get powershell to recognise the image in the document as an image so it's missing it any time it goes to remove it.
Is there another way to programatically remove all images from a word document as the 'shape' stuff in powershell doesn't seem to work half the time. Below is my code:
`# Initialize a variable to store the total shape count
$totalShapeCount = 0
    # Loop through each story range in the document
    foreach ($storyRange in $doc.StoryRanges) {
        # Get the range of the current story
        $currentRange = $storyRange

        # Check if the current story range is not null
        if ($currentRange -ne $null) {
            # Loop through all shapes in the current story range and count them
            $shapeCount = $currentRange.Shapes.Count
            $totalShapeCount += $shapeCount
        }
    }

    # Output the total number of shapes found in the entire document
    Write-Host "Number of shapes found in the entire document: $totalShapeCount"


    # Get the first page range
    $firstPageHeight = $doc.PageSetup.PageHeight - $doc.PageSetup.TopMargin - $doc.PageSetup.BottomMargin
    $firstPageRange = $doc.Range(0, $firstPageHeight)

    # Output the range information for debugging
    Write-Host "First Page Range Start: $($firstPageRange.Start)"
    Write-Host "First Page Range End: $($firstPageRange.End)"

    # Loop through all inline shapes in the first page
    $inlineShapeCount = $firstPageRange.InlineShapes.Count
    Write-Host "Number of inline shapes found on the first page: $inlineShapeCount"
    
    # Loop through all shapes in the first page
    $shapeCount = $firstPageRange.Shapes.Count
    Write-Host "Number of shapes found on the first page: $shapeCount"

    # Loop through all inline shapes in the first page
    foreach ($shape in $firstPageRange.InlineShapes) {
        # Check if the inline shape is an image
        if ($shape.Type -eq 3) { # 3 corresponds to wdInlineShapePicture
            # Delete the image
            $shape.Delete()
            Write-Host "Deleted inline image on the first page"
        }
    }
    
    # Loop through all shapes in the first page and delete images
    foreach ($shape in $firstPageRange.Shapes) {
        if ($shape.Type -eq "msoPicture") {
            $shape.Delete()
            Write-Host "Deleted image on the first page"
        }
    }`

I have tried looping over every inline shape, shape, text box, table in the document to see if any image is in there. It's all coming back as no images in the debugs.

Have another look at the WdInlineShapeType enumeration, where you will find more picture-like values like wdInlineShapeLinkedPicture (value 4), wdInlineShapeLinkedPictureHorizontalLine (value 8) or even wdInlineShapeWebVideo (value 16) etc.
Then there is the MsoShapeType enumeration where you'll find for instance msoGraphic (value 28), msoLinkedGraphic (value 29), msoLinkedPicture (value 11), msoPicture (value 13) etc.

As commented, there are much more shape and inline shape types that you may consider 'images'.
To check if a certain shape has a type you may regard as image, change the foreach loops into this
image-like Inline Shape types
# wdInlineShapePicture, wdInlineShapeLinkedPicture, wdInlineShapePictureHorizontalLine,
# wdInlineShapeLinkedPictureHorizontalLine, wdInlineShapePictureBullet, 
# wdInlineShapeLockedCanvas, wdInlineShapeSmartArt, wdInlineShapeWebVideo
$inlineImages = 3,4,7,8,9,14,15,16
# Loop through all inline shapes in the first page
foreach ($shape in $firstPageRange.InlineShapes) {
    # Check if the inline shape is an image
    if ($shape.Type -in $inlineImages) {
        # Delete the image
        $shape.Delete()
        Write-Host "Deleted inline image on the first page"
    }
}

# or like this:

# $inlineImages = 3,4,7,8,9,14,15,16
# $firstPageRange.InlineShapes | Where-Object {$inlineImages -contains $_.Type} | 
# ForEach-Object { 
#     $_.Delete()
#     Write-Host "Deleted inline image on the first page"
# }

image-like Mso Shape types
# msoLinkedPicture, msoPicture, msoMedia, msoCanvas, msoIgxGraphic, 
# msoWebVideo, msoGraphic, msoLinkedGraphic
$msoImages = 11,13,16,20,24,26,28,29
# Loop through all shapes in the first page and delete images
foreach ($shape in $firstPageRange.Shapes) {
    if ($shape.Type -in $msoImages) {
        $shape.Delete()
        Write-Host "Deleted image on the first page"
    }
}

# or like this:

# $msoImages = 11,13,16,20,24,26,28,29
# $firstPageRange.Shapes | Where-Object {$msoImages -contains $_.Type} | 
# ForEach-Object { 
#     $_.Delete()
#     Write-Host "Deleted image on the first page"
# }


The issue is that the following write-hosts are printing as 0 shapes. No shapes are found in the first page of the doc. I tried analysing the whole document and is still returning 0. Even when there is a picture.
Get the first page range
$firstPageHeight = $doc.PageSetup.PageHeight - $doc.PageSetup.TopMargin - $doc.PageSetup.BottomMargin
$firstPageRange = $doc.Range(0, $firstPageHeight)
Loop through all inline shapes in the first page
$inlineShapeCount = $firstPageRange.InlineShapes.Count
Write-Host "Number of inline shapes found on the first page: $inlineShapeCount"

@DanielSCG I tested my code using $doc.InlineShapes and $doc.Shapes and that worked OK. Perhaps your $firstPageRange stuff is wrong? Needles to say that after the modifications to the document, you need to Save it..

Yes it works for the most part. The code I'm using to test it actually checks the entire doc not just the first page. It works 99% of the time however the specific word document they provided me seems like an outlier the script does not detect any images in it.

@DanielSCG In that case, you might want to check what shape Types are used in that old document you need to test with and possibly add more values to the $msoImages and $inlineImages arrays. Because i do not have your test document, it is impossible to help you on that specific example.. In the meantime, it would be helpful if you would accept my answer so others may find it more easily.
